# Xamarin.Forms OAuth Token authentication

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, token, httpclient

I tried make it as you suggested (answer below this). Unfortunately still I have this problem. 
This is my new TokenService.cs:
class TokenService

```
{
    TokenKeeper tokenkeeper;

    public TokenService()
    {
        tokenkeeper = new TokenKeeper();
    }

    public async void AwaitGetToken()
    {
        tokenkeeper = new TokenKeeper();
        tokenkeeper = await GetToken();          
    }

    private async Task<TokenKeeper> GetToken()
    {
        string stringuri = string.Format("{0}/token", RestAccess.HostUrl);

        var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        dict.Add("grant_type", "password");
        dict.Add("username", RestAccess.User);
        dict.Add("password", RestAccess.Pass);
        dict.Add("client_id", RestAccess.Client_ID);
        dict.Add("client_secret", RestAccess.Client_secret);

        tokenkeeper=new TokenKeeper();
        var httpclient = new HttpClient();
        try
        {
            var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, stringuri) { Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(dict) };
            var res = await httpclient.SendAsync(req);
            if (res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var content = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                tokenkeeper = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenKeeper>(content);
                return tokenkeeper;
            }

            return tokenkeeper;
        }
        catch
        {
            return tokenkeeper;
        }
        finally
        {
            httpclient.CancelPendingRequests();
            httpclient.Dispose();   
        }
    }
}
```

My tokenkeeper is simple class:

```
public class TokenKeeper
    {
        public string access_token { get; set; }
        public string refresh_token { get; set; }
        public TokenKeeper()
        {
            access_token = "";
            refresh_token = "";
        }
    }
```

In my calling code I have as below:

```
...
tokenservice.AwaitGetToken();  
GetXFMapUserFromAzureAndSetVariable(RestAccess.User);  
_navigationService.NavigateAsync("ZleceniaListContentPage", par);
...
```

tokenservice.AwaitGetToken() and GEtXFMapUserFromAzureAndSetVariable(RestAccess.User) they are similar. Both await but tokenservice.AwaitGetToken() is POST and  GEtXFMapUserFromAzureAndSetVariable is GET. 
GEtXFMapUserFromAzureAndSetVariable is working correctly but if I call tokenservice.AwaitGetToken() the aplication get the token but before it's continue. At the end the instruction GEtXFMapUserFromAzureAndSetVariable it is being done tokenservice.AwaitGetToken() responds.

How can I wait with call GEtXFMapUserFromAzureAndSetVariable until I receive a reply from tokenservice.AwaitGetToken() ???

Comment: Looking at the method definition `GetTokenPublic` n `TokenService` class, I assume that you are not awaiting the token fetch, await it until you get the response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete your `AwaitGetToken` method, it is useless.
Now make you `GetToken` method public and call it with await:

```
await tokenService.GetToken();
await GetXFMapUserFromAzureAndSetVariable(RestAccess.User);
await _navigationService.NavigateAsync("ZleceniaListContentPage", par);
```

Basically you always need to await methods returning `Task`, or it will run in a parallel fashion, and you will lose consistency in your code.

You seem very confused by `Task` and `async/await`, I will strongly advise you to read tutorials and docs on it:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/

Comment: I made this, but maybe it's problem because the method where I call tokenService.GetToken() is binding method and it navigates to next View. It's declared as public void GoToZleceniaListContentPageNavigation(). And I have problem to use await tokenService.GetToken() - it's incorrect. Therefore I created  tokenservice.AwaitGetToken(). Can't I do that? This GetXFMapUserFromAzureAndSetVariable(RestAccess.User) works correct. And it is made similar. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry mate I don't understand a word you are saying. I can just advise you to learn more about tasks. You seem to miss a lot of the whole logic.

Comment: Thank you very much :-) I traced the code again and I found a stupid mistake. I correct it and all your tips are working!! Thank you